# Why is the diagram not coming (though it does not throw any error)?

Tags: pstricks, pspicture

```
\begin{document}
%\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\begin{pspicture}


\begin{figure}
\psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,25.15)(11.7,27.25)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](4.0,27.05)(0.0,25.15)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{<-}(4.1,26.05)(7.3,26.05)(7.7,26.05)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](11.7,27.25)(7.7,25.15)
\rput[bl](8.6,26.15){SOUVIK}
\rput[bl](0.4,25.95){IIT}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{pspicture}
%\end{TeXtoEPS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ, and which packages are loaded in the preamble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should throw some error !
Try this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

%>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
\begin{document}
%\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\begin{figure}


\psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,25.15)(11.7,27.25)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](4.0,27.05)(0.0,25.15)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{<-}(4.1,26.05)(7.3,26.05)(7.7,26.05)
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](11.7,27.25)(7.7,25.15)
\rput[bl](8.6,26.15){SOUVIK}
\rput[bl](0.4,25.95){IIT}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{figure}

%\end{TeXtoEPS}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like an export from a graphic program. If you have no caption then do not use the `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}(0,25.15)(11.7,27.25)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04](4.0,27.05)(0.0,25.15)
\psline[linewidth=0.04,arrowinset=0.0]{<-}(4.1,26.05)(7.3,26.05)(7.7,26.05)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](11.7,27.25)(7.7,25.15)
\rput[bl](8.6,26.15){SOUVIK}
\rput[bl](0.4,25.95){IIT}
\end{pspicture}
%\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

BTW: Using nodes makes the code easier ...